# Vue V-for on selected index

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I wanna know how to v-for on a multidimensional array with selected index, because when I go with this code it does not work.

```
<div v-for="button in pull.button_response[key]">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, index and object like an enum, so

```
<div v-for="(index, button) in pull" :key="index">
    <p>test {{ button[index] }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
//===== just to remove warnings
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false
//==============================

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pull: {
      button_response: {
        a: [
          1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        ],
        b: [
          6, 7, 8, 9, 10
        ]
      }
    },
    key: ['a', 'b']
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div>
       <select v-model="key">
         <option value="a">a</option>
         <option value="b">b</option>
       </select>
       <br/>
       <div v-for="button in pull.button_response[key]">
          <p>{{button}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```